# Automatically add a folder (document set) by code (generating the name also by code, without the user inputting the name)

Tags: development, visual-studio, object-model

I want to know if it’s possible to write en Event Receiver in VB for automating the creation of a document set: the user only click “new document set” and then the code generates the document set with an automated name, without  the windows where the user input the name and other properties for the doc set.

If it’s possible, what are the basic steps? (Which function to override, etc ) ?

By the way, is it possible in the same code to create inside this document set a new empty form based on form template ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with document sets yet but I can suggest a solution. You can replace the related buttons in the ribbon with your own via declarative ribbon customization and redirect users to the custom aspx page with the code (and with no UI at all) to take all the required actions. Then you need to redirect user to the result page or back to the original list view.